# Migrate Custom Domain attached to an existing Amplify app to a new Amplify App

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, custom-domain

I have an amplify app which is serving dev and production traffic. I have mapped a root domain (ex: https://example.dcp.com for prod and https://dev.example.dcp.com to dev). Now I have created a new Amplify app which is hosting qa env and I was able to configure the custom subdomain https://qa.example.dcp.com to qa branch of this new Amplify app. I want to now move the production env to the new Amplify app, such that https://example.dcp.com should point to new Amplify app prod branch. The DNS records are maintained in google domains.

I want to know how I can make the change for production domain from old APP to new App without deleting the old APP ( I read that we need to delete the old App to remove the CNAME mapping with the cloudfront distribution).

Can I achieve this without deleting the old App completely and just remove the association with the prod env?(by deleting the CNAME record for old prod Amplify Cloudfront url in google domains and using exclude root option in Amplify console). As I would still like to use the old Amplify app to serve as dev environment.

[I understand its better to keep multiple env as part of same Amplify app, but due to project constraints I need the dev and qa,prod env in separate Apps].

Please do share your inputs on this.